# getting rollup to resolve extensionless imports in node_modules for browser bundling

Tags: rollupjs

rollup gives me errors like these when trying to import an NPM module:

```
main.js → stdout...
[!] Error: Could not load myfolder\node_modules\three\examples\jsm\renderers\CSS2DRenderer (imported by node_modules/openbim-components/core/SimpleRenderer/index.js): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'myfolder\node_modules\three\examples\jsm\renderers\CSS2DRenderer'
Error: Could not load myfolder\node_modules\three\examples\jsm\renderers\CSS2DRenderer (imported by node_modules/openbim-components/core/SimpleRenderer/index.js): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'myfolder\node_modules\three\examples\jsm\renderers\CSS2DRenderer'
```

The immediate cause is, that e.g.
`node_modules/openbim-components/core/SimpleRenderer/index.js`
contains imports like
`import { CSS2DRenderer } from "three/examples/jsm/renderers/CSS2DRenderer";`

That is, Typescript style, or nodeJS style, without the .js suffix.
(If I manually edit every single such import to include the .js suffix, the error goes away, but that is not the way..)

To clarify: The actual file is called CSS2DRenderer.js, WITH suffix.

I have tried figuring out from rollup.js documentation, what controls the handling/matching of suffix.
It seems commonJS mode would support omitting the suffix?
But openbim-components, to my knowledge, is not a commonJS module? (If I am mistaken here, that may be the answer?).

I am using
`"@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.1"` 
in my
rollup.config.mjs,
as is apparently the way to use npm modules with rollup..?
But its documentation does not mention any mechanisms regarding default/missing .js suffix.

Somewhere in rollup's internals, lives a function called `addJsExtensionIfNecessary()`, but it is apparently not assisting me here.. presumably, because it is tied to commonJS..?

I have tried to solve the issue using the additional rollup plugins
'rollup-plugin-includepaths' and 'rollup-plugin-resolve',
which sound like they might help with this issue, but instead they just make it worse(?)

My goal is to use rollup to build the bundle.js file for a web page.
Weirdly, the tool vite seems to handle this case, and vite internally uses rollup.
But I am not in a position where I can just tell people to switch to vite
(my proper goal is to make sure we can use the openbim-components tool generally in my company, so it must 'work in general', not just in a special case.)

I feel like I am missing some knowledge on how to use rollup properly.

Comment: What is your rollup.js version?

Comment: @HarshalPatil  it is rollup v3.29.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.

The `openbim-components` is published as ESM-only, however, the `package.json` file doesn't specify `"type": "module"`. Either files should have `*.mjs` extension or `type: "module"` should be specified. However, since you are using bundler, that won't cause this problem. It becomes a problem only when you intend to run this code on Node.js runtime.

Now, the next issue is problematic. The package `three` on which `openbim-components` depends on is using ESM and correctly specifies `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` file. However at the same time, it is using the new [exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports) field. This is how it is specified:

```json
{
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./build/three.module.js",
      "require": "./build/three.cjs"
    },
    "./examples/fonts/*": "./examples/fonts/*",
    "./examples/jsm/*": "./examples/jsm/*",
    "./addons/*": "./examples/jsm/*",
    "./src/*": "./src/*",
    "./nodes": "./examples/jsm/nodes/Nodes.js"
  },
}
```

**This is the problem**. These are not properly specified. As per the spec, the extension-less imports should specify the **extension** on the right side like this:

```json
{
  "exports": {
    "./examples/jsm/*": "./examples/jsm/*.js",
    "./addons/*": "./examples/jsm/*.js",
    "./src/*": "./src/*.js",
  }
}
```

Either, there should be extension on both side or if the author of the library wants the user to use extension-less imports, then only on the right hand side should be specified. The point being that the exports map should correctly map to the correct file with its extension.

[Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) and [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias) provides a alias resolution which you could have used here like. The Rollup doesn't provide anything out of box for this but it has an official plugin - [`@rollup/plugin-alias`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-alias) that may help you achieve this:

```js
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';

export default {
  // ...other configuration
  plugins: [
    alias({
      entries: [
        // Or something similar to this configuration
        {
          find: 'three/examples/jsm/renderers/CSS2DRenderer',
          replacement: 'three/examples/jsm/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js'
        },
      ]
    })
  ]
};
```

*I never used aliasing with Rollup before; but that is the only way for now. Also, consider raising issues with both the repositories.*

Comment: I'm still looking at this 3 weeks later. Unfortunately, I was too eager to accept an answer.
Answer claims the suffix is required on the right hand side, in the subpath clauses in the exports field of the package.json.
But I don't see this in the nodejs documentation explicitly stated anywhere? All its _examples_ specify the .js suffix, but nothing it said on it?
Very little is said regarding the right hand path.  Only "must be relative  file url starting with "./"
Where is right hand side defined in specs?

Comment: UPDATE: I may have found an answer:
I may have found an answer myself (not sure). I found this:

https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-patterns

..containing:

.. This is a direct static matching and replacement without any special handling for file extensions. Including the "*.js" on both sides of the mapping restricts the exposed package exports to only JS files.  ..

IF I read it correctly, it is _not_ legal to leave out the .js suffix ("without any special handling"). That is, it would not map 'extensionlessname' to 'extensionlessname.js' then.

Comment: @jakobgaardsted Yes. That's the same link from the answer. It contains some examples but those are not very clear. Also, as the doc says - `This is a direct static matching and replacement without any special handling for file extensions.` It means, if you leave out the `*.js` extension, it doesn't matter. The decision then is determined by what caller is asking and if that ask is properly mapped to the real file or not! That leads to ambiguity. Thus it makes sense to have extensions on both the sides.